# Парсинг значений

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, возникла проблема с получением значений. Я новичок в плане работы Python+selenium.
Мне нужно получить элементы которые указаны зелёной стрелкой (44. 1443, 363) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вывести их списком.
я пробую сделать так:

```
likes=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/b')

for spisok in likes:

print(spisok.text)
```

В ответ получаю только первое значение (44)

Comment: Ну правильно, в пути указана дорога только к одному первому значению. Путь до других значений другой ведь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно искать по имени класса (кода страницы нет, поэтому исхожу из того, что все лайки имеют одинаковый класс):

```
likes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fa fa-heart pull-left")
```

Вернет список всех найденных элементов.

NB. Не путать с похожей функцией `find_element_by_class_name` (без "s" в `elements`), которая возвращает только первый найденный элемент.